# redefine single attribute of a derived class method

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a `Server` class:

```
class Server
{
    private SqlConnectionStringBuilder _sqlConnectionStringBuilder;

    public SqlConnectionStringBuilder SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        get { return _sqlConnectionStringBuilder; }
        set { _sqlConnectionStringBuilder = value; }
    }

    public List<Database> getDeployableDatabases() {
        // the connectionString is different
        String connectionString = this.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;

        // do something (this part is equal in every subclass)
    }
}
```

From `Server` class many other class can inherit (for example the development server, said `DevServer` class). Each derived class should reimplement `getDeployableDatabases` method just to redefine the `connectionString` attribute. Since this add a lot of duplicated code, the question is: how can I write the `DevServer` class (and the `Server` class if needed) in a OO perspective?

Comment: Can you show example how you redefine `connectionString`?

Comment: use the `connectionString` as property and edit it at the parent when creating `DevServer` object. Then use the parent's `getDeployableDatabases()` method to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and redefine your string in a specific abstract method that has to be implemented by every deriving class.

Comment: good idea but server class is not abstract in the example above so he has to use a virtual method or property

Answer (score 0):

You can define a virtual internal property with an getter to get your connection string.
in your methode you can use this property to get the connection string. so you have only override this property in your subclasses.